# Planar Brownian Motion hitting times

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\textbf{B(t)} = (B_{1}(t), B_{2}(t))$ be a standard two dimensional Brownian motion starting from $(0, 0)$.

(a) For each $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$, show that there exists a number $\alpha > 0$ such that $X(t) = α(x_{1}B_{1}(t)+ x_{2}B_{2}(t))$ is a standard one dimensional Brownian motion.

(b) Let $\tau_{1}$ be the first time that $\textbf{B(t)}$ hits the line $m_{1}x + y = c$ and $\tau_{2}$ be the first time that $\textbf{B(t)}$ hits the line $m_{2}x - y = c$. Find $\mathbb{P}[\tau_{1} \land \tau_{2} < 1]$. Here, $m_{1}m_{2} = -1$.

(c) Let $\tau$ be the first time that $\textbf{B(t)}$ hits either of the lines $ax + y = b$ or $ax + y = −b$. Show that

$$\mathbb{E}(\tau) = b^2/(1+a^2) $$

(d) Let $\tilde{\tau}$ be the first time that $\textbf{B(t)}$ hits the line $x + y = \sqrt{2}$. Find 
$$\mathbb{E}(e^{\tilde{\tau}/2})$$

$\textbf{My Attempt}$

a) we know that $\textbf{B(t)}$ has a bivariate normal distribution so any linear combination would be a univariate normal distribution.

$$\mathbb{E}(X(t)) = 0$$.

For $s < t$, 
$$Cov[X(s), X(t)] = Cov[\alpha x_{1}B_{1}(t), \alpha x_{1}B_{1}(s)] + Cov[\alpha x_{1}B_{1}(t), \alpha x_{2}B_{2}(s)] + Cov[\alpha x_{2}B_{2}(t), \alpha x_{1}B_{1}(s)] + Cov[\alpha x_{1}B_{1}(s), \alpha x_{2}B_{2}(s)] = \alpha^2 x_{1}^2 s + \alpha^2 x_{2}^2 s = \alpha^2(x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2)s.$$
If we let $\alpha^2 = 1/(x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2)$, then $Cov[X(s), X(t)] = s.$ Thus, we have shown that X(t) is a Gaussian process with mean 0, and $Cov[X(s), X(t)] = min(s,t)$. Hence, it is a one dimensional BM.

b) I know that the lines are perpendicular. Define the new processes,

$$X_{1}(t) = B_{2}(t) + m_{1}B_{1}(t)$$
$$X_{2}(t) = -B_{2}(t) + m_{2}B_{1}(t)$$

$X_{1}(t)$ and $X_{2}$ are BM, so they are Gaussian processes, and we only need to show that their covariance is 0.

$$Cov(X_{1}(t) , X_{2}(t)) = Cov(B_{2}(t) + m_{1}B_{1}(t), - B_{2}(t) + m_{2}B_{1}(t) = - Cov(B_{2}(t), B_{2}(t)) + Cov(B_{2}(t), m_{1}B_{1}(t)) + Cov(m_{1}B_{t}, B_{2}(t)) + Cov(m_{1}B_{1}(t),m_{2}B_{1}(t)) = t-t=0 $$

Hence, $X_{1}(t)$ , $X_{2}(t)$ are independent of each other. Next, we calculate the distance between where X_{1}(t) starts and the line $m_{2}x - y = c$. The distance equals $c/\sqrt{m_{1}^2 + 1}$. Thus,

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < 1) = 2\mathbb{P}\Bigg(X_{1}(t) > \frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{1}^2 + 1}}\Bigg) = 2 - 2\Phi\Bigg(\frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{1}^2 + 1}}\Bigg),$$

where $\Phi(.)$ is the CDF of a standard normal random variable.

Similarly,

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_{2} < 1) = 2\mathbb{P}\Bigg(X_{2}(t) > \frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{2}^2 + 1}}\Bigg) = 2 - 2\Phi\Bigg(\frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{2}^2 + 1}}\Bigg).$$

Since, $X_{1}(t)$ and $X_{2}(t)$ are independent, so $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ are also independent.

$$\mathbb{P}[\tau_{1} \land \tau_{2} < 1] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[\tau_{1} > 1]\mathbb{P}[\tau_{2} > 1] = 1 - \Bigg[2 - 2\Phi\Bigg(\frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{1}^2 + 1}}\Bigg)\Bigg]\Bigg[2 - 2\Phi\Bigg(\frac{c}{\sqrt{m_{2}^2 + 1}}\Bigg)\Bigg]$$

c) The distance between the two given (parallel) lines is $\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}.$ We make use of the optional stopping theorem (OST) and part a). We choose two appropriate martingales and the two points as $\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$. The distance between those points is $\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$. Using OST for the first martingale gives us, the probability that the BM hits $\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ first as $1/2$. Thus, by symmetry the probability that the BM hits $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ first is also $1/2$.

$$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{\tau}] = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}\Bigg) + \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}\Bigg) = \Bigg(\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}\Bigg).$$

d) If I can get the density of $\tilde{\tau}$, then I just need the moment generating function evaluated at 1/2.

Alternatively, I know in 1-D that we can also define a new martingale and then calculate this quantity directly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the lines right? If the second line is $m_2x+y=c,$ then $X^1:=m_1 B_1+B_2$ and $X^2:=m_2B_1+B_2$ are independent just by computing their covariance and then you can apply part $a)$ to each part separately to get the probability that one of the stopping times is smaller than 1. In part $c$, just apply part $a)$ to reduce this to a 1-D problem.

Comment: I did get the lines right. Yeah, part a) does say that any projection will be a BM. But when I project BM in part b), I am worried about shifting the axes. I want to make these two lines as my new coordinate axes and then use the projection of BM.

Comment: Not quite. $\mathbb{P}(\tau_1\wedge \tau_2<1)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_1<1)+\mathbb{P}(\tau_2<1)-\mathbb{P}(\tau_1<1,\tau_2<1)$, and assuming independence, you can simplify the expression.

Comment: I guess it's more natural to say $\mathbb{P}(\tau_1\wedge \tau_2<1)=1-\mathbb{P}(\tau_1\wedge \tau_2\geq 1)=1-\mathbb{P}(\tau_1\geq 1)\mathbb{P}(\tau_2\geq 1)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Do b) and c) look correct to you? How would I go about d). I could try to get the density but that'd be tedious. I could also make use of an exponential martingale. Thanks

Comment: In $c$ you are not computing the mean of $\tilde{\tau}$, but rather the mean of $B_{\tilde{\tau}}$. To get the time by itself you should use that for a $1-D$ Brownian Motion $W$, $W^2_t-t$ is a Martingale and apply the OST to that one. Other than that, your arguments look fine up to typoes. For $d$, I'd guess it's best to use an exponential martingale, yes.